# Script in TexStudio with selection of text

Tags: texstudio

**First approach**: I first tried to create the normal macro in TexStudio

```
\begin{cases}%|&\text{}\\
&\text{}\end{cases}
```

but TexStudio has problem with it, I assume because of the double backslash.
If I leave TexStudio and start it again the macro is mutilated.
I should fill a bug.

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2: The macro works:
[image]

Step 3:
I leave the edit and start it again, result:
[image]

**Second approach**: now I tried this script:

```
%SCRIPT
editor.write("\\begin{cases}???&\\text{}\\\\ \n")
editor.write("&\\text{}\\end{cases}")
----------   from here -------------
cursor.movePosition(cursorEnums.Up)
cursor.movePosition(cursorEnums.EndOfLine)
cursor.movePosition(10,cursorEnums.Left)
cursor.selectionStart(); 
cursor.movePosition(3,,cursorEnums.Right, cursorEnums.KeepAnchor);
cursor.selectionEnd();
```

the Qt script does what I wanted initially do, but in the second part I want to select the "???" and I don't now which method has to be used . The error is at `selectionStart`.

> Approach 1: Is a known issue? Work around?
>
> Approach 2:
> How can I solve the problem?
> is the cursor an instance of this: [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html)?

Here a similar question: [Macro phrase selection and line selection for texstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399039), that does need a general curson movement.

Also interesting would be to be able in the script to produce a placeholder, but that is perhaps too much.

Comment: What do you expect when run the macro? `\begin{cases}
&\text{%|}\\
\end{cases}` produces the `cases` environment with cursor positioned inside the braces.

Comment: @Sigur Approach 1? Yes, just copy and paste of the code where `%|` is meant to place the cursor

Comment: @Sigur Have you left the editor , started it again, and used the macro again?

Comment: Yes. It works well. Simply type that command in the macro editor in the Normal, not Script nor Environment.

Comment: @Sigur For me it does not work. I don't know why. Thus the second approach is the only one for me.

Comment: @Sigur 2.12.14, since the last one has an incompatibility with the libs (Fedora 28)

Comment: I use 2.2.16 but I don't think this is the problem. Did you type the macro as Normal code, as I told you? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Sigur, sure, I wrote 20 macros with all possible options (mirror, persistent, ...) every thing fine up to the double backslash. The double backslash is the problem, without it , it works.

Comment: So, what is the problem with the macro? 1. the double backslashes does not appear? 2. the cursor is not positioned in braces?

Comment: @Sigur Approach 1: the macro work BUT leaving the editor the macro get corrupted. Approach 2: the text ??? is not selected

Comment: Ah, ok, so maybe some problem with permissions to write in some ini txs file in your home folder.

Comment: @Sigur, no, I write all other macros, inclusive this one. I edited the question

Comment: What happens if you try `\text{}\\%` in the macro?

Comment: In `~/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini` there is the line for the `foo` macro I had created: `Macros\0=foo, \\begin{cases}\n%|&\\text{}\\\\\n&\\text{}\n\\end{cases}, , :ccc:` What do you have?

Comment: @Sigur cool, it works! this is a workaround for the first approach.  For the second approach it would interest me what is behind cursor, with a ref to the Qt documentation.

Comment: I have `Macros\24=cc, \\begin{cases}%|&\\text{}\\\\\n&\\text{}\\end{cases}, , :cc:`, that is, the error is by reading the macro at the start.

Comment: Well, good that some partial fix you found.

Comment: @Sigur you found it, thank you!